# Come e quando si usa la frase "Altro che"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adverbs

In una conversazione sul [Bar Sport](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11367/2019/10/7) si è usata la frase "Altro che". Questo ha attirato la mia attenzione perché non avevo mai visto o sentito la locuzione "altro che" usata in questo modo. Tra l'altro, avevo sempre avuto l'impressione che il pronome "altro" si usasse di solito per indicare "contrario" o "diverso" di quello che si aveva detto precedentemente. Il mio dubbio è se nella frase "Altro che" è anche così o è invece tutto il contrario, oppure dipende dal contesto. Come spiego qui sotto, ho cercato sul dizionario, ma non sono sicura di averne colto tutte le sfumature.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altro2) ho trovato

> Come esclam., non com., *altro!*, per affermare energicamente: *«Partiresti volentieri?» «Altro!»*; *a. se lo conosco!*; e con più forza: *eh altro!, altro che!* (v. anche altroché).

Anche alla voce ["altroché"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altroche) si può leggere

> usato spesso, spec. nel linguaggio fam., come esclamazione energicamente affermativa: *se mi piace? a.!; a. se lo conosco!; a. se ci andrei volentieri!; «Ma l’hai veduto proprio con i tuoi occhi?» «Altroché!»*.

Ora, se avessi sentito un dialogo con le battute *«Partiresti volentieri?» «Altro che!»* prima di aver letto queste entrate del dizionario, avrei capito che la persona che ha risposto non vuole per niente partire. Tuttavia, se ho compreso bene la spiegazione del Treccani, il significato è tutto il contrario: questa persona sta affermando energicamente che ha una gran voglia di partire. È veramente così? Potreste fare altri esempi di uso di "Altro che" che aiutino a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Altro” e “altroché” usati come esclamazione hanno sempre un’accezione positiva; cioè, in questo uso, "altro" non ha il significato di "diverso" o "contrario" di quello che si è detto precedentemente. Lo possiamo leggere in parecchi dizionari:

> ***[Altroché](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/altroche.shtml)***
>   [al-tro-ché] o ”altro che” esclamazione.
>
> Certamente, come no, in risposte enfaticamente affermative: “C'era gente?” “Altroché!”

([Sabatini Coletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/altroche.shtml))

> certamente sì (usato in risposte affermative decise): *«Hai mangiato bene?» «Altroché! Era tutto buonissimo»*

([Garzanti](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=altroch%C3%A9))

> altroché
>   - avv.
>   1909; dalla loc. altro che.
>
> fam., certamente, sì: *vuoi venire? altroché!*

([De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/altroche))

Comment: Quindi, in questi usi, "altro" non ha mai il senso di "contrario" o "diverso" di quello che si è detto prima, no?

Comment: @Charo - l’uso di “altro” che citi da Treccani, come specificato è poco comune. Io non lo userei. Comunque   il significato e l’uso è lo stesso di altroché.

Comment: Mi riferivo a "altro" in "Altro che" usato nel modo che spieghi nella tua risposta. In questo uso di "Altro che", "altro" non ha mai il senso di "contrario" o "diverso" di quello che si è detto prima, no?

Comment: @Charo - non nell’uso citato sopra.

Comment: Questo era il mio dubbio. Adesso ho capito, ma forse si potrebbe aggiungere alla risposta in modo più esplicito.